# Execute drush commands from UI?

Tags: drush

So i wrote a lot of custom code which is executed form custom drush commands from the command line/terminal, works fine, but now the client changes his mind and want to execute the code from the UI, the admin panel.

Is there any way i can run those drush commands from that level or not?

Thanks,
Will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in php you can do something like :

> shell_exec("drush status");

if this is temporary, you can execute it from devel/php, but if it's a production site solution that you need, you can per example add a custom form that does this in its submit method